# Error 'Xamarin/Xamarin.h' file not found (Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: xcode, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.mac

I'm a mac developer trying out xamarin. I first tried Xamarin.Mac, but found that there was barely any support on that, so I added in Xamarin.Forms by adding some code and importing a NuGet package.

I'm using xcode for UI design and Visual Studio Mac 2022 for this, but whenever I try to run it throws the error `'xamarin/xamarin.h' file not found`. I don't have a xamarin.h file, and don't know how to create one.

Comment: Two suggestions: **1)** Use [Visual Studio 2022 for mac](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/mac/preview/) rather than developing directly in xcode. **2)** Create a `Maui (Preview)` project, and put source files in `MacCatalyst` folder, to use iOS UIKit etc on mac. NOTE: Have patience; looks like MacCatalyst support is quite new. I think you need to edit the `YourProject.csproj` file to enable it - see the comment in that file's xml. (If there is no comment related to MacCatalyst, then csproj should work without editing.)  Should improve over the next couple of months.

Comment: Forgot to add this, I'm using visual studio for mac to write the code and just using xcode because it told me to, and I'm using it for UI. Also, don't really know how/what maui is (Is it something to do with xamarin?).

Comment: if you are using Xamarin Forms you generally won't use XCode

Comment: Maui is the successor to xamarin. Most of it is the same as xamarin. Its on the verge of finalizing. For now, most of the documentation to use is xamarin. Also most of the examples you find. But Jason is correct: whether you use xamarin or maui, you need xcode installed and up-to-date, but visual studio should use xcode automatically. Do you have a link to a tutorial that mentions xcode?

Comment: This error is kinda pointless, as I can run it in visual studio and the app runs and all, just very curious as to why it's not running in Xcode

Comment: The tutorial I'm following is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/other/mac

Comment: ok. I see mention of editing UI via xcode in other Xamarin.Mac docs also. Maybe some change in VS or xcode has "broken" how that works. Years ago, VS' internal equivalent to xcode storyboard had limitations, such that xcode was a welcome alternative for certain tasks [e.g. custom cells; complex constraints]; hopefully that is no longer needed.

Comment: A more offtopic thing if anyone knows, how do I change what layer an item is on? Like how would I place one behind another, or on top.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean; best to create a new question, and show the exact code or UI you are working with.